# Anaconda won't force quit in Mac

Tags: python, anaconda, anaconda3

I can't seem to force quit Anaconda-Navigator. It is apparently running on my Mac but when i try to force quit it nothing happens, and when i try to launch it also nothing happens. Any help is welcomed.

Comment: Have you tried deleting Anaconda-Navigator and reinstalling? It may also help to try restarting your Mac.

Comment: the application might be corrupted

Answer (score 2):

This problem only occurs when you first close the terminals and then 'Anaconda'. **Do following steps:**

1. Restart your Mac.
2. It won't happen again if you always close the 'Anaconda' first and then the Terminals (The two small windows).

Hope it was helpful!